# How do we get these parameters in create carrier rate quote API in WFS: shipmentSource, customerId, customerName, locationName

Tags: walmart-api, fulfillment, wfs

I am trying to get carrier for an inbound shipment to Walmart fulfilment centre that I created. I am able to download shipment label for that shipment, the next step is to get carrier and its estimated charge. The API is shown in screenshot: [API description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gN8v.png). Please also tell if there is any new version for it. I think this is the latest.

Base URL used is: https://marketplace.walmartapis.com. I created an inbound shipment (to walmart fulfilment centre) for WFS eligible items, it returned a shipment with shipmentId and other info (No Carrier info as yet not assigned:(POST) /v3/fulfillment/inbound-shipments. I am able to download shipping label for the given shipmentId: (POST) /v3/fulfillment/label.
The create carrier rate quote API, will get the carrier and estimated charges for the shipment. I found that this API is needed by checking the browser console when I do the steps for setting up shipment in my account. In those steps I was able to get a carrier and its charges for the shipment in my account in the browser.
But I don't have any info on these params: shipmentSource, customerId, customerName, locationName, that are required in create carrier rate quote API.